# Rails: can I use polymorphic references with non-integer primary keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, uuid

I have a database that uses UUIDs as primary keys, like this:

```
create_table "my_table", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
 t.string "id", :limit => 36
end
```

However, when I try to use :references for foreign keys to that table, it generates integer columns for the ID.  Can :references be instructed to deal with a non-integer ID?  My migration for the referring table is like this:

```
create_table "child_table" :id => false, :force => true do |t|
 t.string "id", :limit => 36
 t.references :my_table
end
```

I know that I could just manually create `:my_table_id` and `:my_table_type` columns, but I'm wondering whether `:references` can be made to do its magic under these circumstances so that I don't have to handle the id+type explicitly throughout my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, `references` only creates integer columns as of this writing.

I'm sure you could override the `references` method to do what you want. But IMO you'd be better off specifying your UUID columns and type columns explicitly. That way the code is clear about what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Yep, I've just checked the activerecord source and it's hardcoded for the ID to be an integer.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. Use `type: :uuid` (as of Rails 4.2).

Answer (score 27):

A :type option has been added when referencing since Rails 4.2

```
t.references :car, type: :uuid, index: true
```

For example:

```
def change
  enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'
  create_table :cars, id: :uuid do |t|
    t.integer :seats
    # And other car-specific things
  end
  create_table :wheels do |t|
    t.references :car, type: :uuid, index: true
    t.integer :radius
    # And other wheel-specific things
  end
end
```

source: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16231